# How to Android JSON Multi Array parsing

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

The work is being seen through the Json data server API for Android.
For general Json format it shows the data well.
However, in the case with the arrangement of the multi-JSON it may not show the data.

I have an JSON something like:

```
  {
    "RESULT": "1",
    "ERROR": "",
    "UNIFORM": [
        {
            "UNIFORMINFO": [
                {
                    "UniformInventoryID": "29",
                    "UniformName": "생활복",
                    "UniformCreated": "2015",
                    "SeasonType": "2",
                    "Sex": "0",
                    "Size": "L",
                    "UniformImage": "URL",
                    "UniformStock": "147"
                },
                {
                    "UNIFORMBYCOST": [
                        {
                            "CostName": "단품가",
                            "UniformCost": "30000"
                        },
                        {
                            "CostName": "세트가",
                            "UniformCost": "20000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "UNIFORMINFO": [
                {
                    "UniformInventoryID": "28",
                    "UniformName": "생활복",
                    "UniformCreated": "2015",
                    "SeasonType": "2",
                    "Sex": "0",
                    "Size": "M",
                    "UniformImage": "URL",
                    "UniformStock": "147"
                },
                {
                    "UNIFORMBYCOST": [
                        {
                            "CostName": "단품가",
                            "UniformCost": "35000"
                        },
                        {
                            "CostName": "세트가",
                            "UniformCost": "25000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "UNIFORMINFO": [
                {
                    "UniformInventoryID": "26",
                    "UniformName": "생활복",
                    "UniformCreated": "2015",
                    "SeasonType": "2",
                    "Sex": "1",
                    "Size": "M",
                    "UniformImage": "URL",
                    "UniformStock": "147"
                },
                {
                    "UNIFORMBYCOST": [
                        {
                            "CostName": "단품가",
                            "UniformCost": "50000"
                        },
                        {
                            "CostName": "세트가",
                            "UniformCost": "40000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I Try to resolve in Android :

```
 private void LISTUNIFORM_RESULT() {
        try {
            JSONObject json_ListUniform = new JSONObject(_LISTUNIFORM_RESPONSE);

            if(json_ListUniform.getString("RESULT").equals("1")) {
                JSONArray UNIFORM_ARRAY = json_ListUniform.getJSONArray("UNIFORM");

                for(int i = 0; i < UNIFORM_ARRAY.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject UNIFORM_OBJ = UNIFORM_ARRAY.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY = UNIFORM_OBJ.getJSONArray("UNIFORMINFO");

                    for(int j = 0; j < UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject UNIFOMINFO_OBJ = UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(j);

                        UniformInventoryID = UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(j).getString("UniformInventoryID");

                        JSONArray UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY = UNIFOMINFO_OBJ.getJSONArray("UNIFORMBYCOST");

                        for(int z = 0; z < UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.length(); z++) {
                            CostName = UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.getJSONObject(z).getString("CostName");
                            UniformCost= UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.getJSONObject(z).getString("UniformCost");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("MIPOS.IO", "JSON Result ` Exception : " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

But it not resolved.

```
08-11 14:29:51.200    8162-8162/? D/MIPOS.IO﹕ JSON Result ` Exception : org.json.JSONException: No value for UNIFORMBYCOST
```

What should I do if the parsing of multiple arrays of these json?

Comment: First check that JSON is correct or not.. use this to check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks! but that's JSON data is valid.

Comment: But when I post your json there it showed me invalid

Comment: More Json format, then import the data repeatedly but it seems that only a part.
Now that will not fix the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"UNIFORMINFO" is an array which has two elements, one has some details & another is an array.
You can't  use getJSONArray("UNIFORMBYCOST") for j=0 as at index 0 there is no such array.
Modify your code like:

```
JSONObject UNIFOMINFO_OBJ = UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(0);

                    UniformInventoryID = UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(j).getString("UniformInventoryID");

                    JSONArray UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY = UNIFORMINFO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("UNIFORMBYCOST");

                    for(int z = 0; z < UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.length(); z++) {
                        CostName = UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.getJSONObject(z).getString("CostName");
                        UniformCost= UNIFORMBYCOST_ARRAY.getJSONObject(z).getString("UniformCost");

                    }
```

Do not use for loop of j.

Comment: Oh, my God!
Only now I've been resolved.
Your help is really big! I really appreciate it.

Time remaining hope a good day ~

Comment: What's the need of effective array of UNIFORMINFO addition UNIFORM also to parsing?

Comment: UNIFORM is an array which contains UNIFORMINFO array which further contains UNIFORMBYCOST array. You have to go step by step to get an array.

Comment: pls help me to do dynamically ge tvalues from uniform, i have the same api